# Extract and Search a Column

Tags: imacros

I have a {{!COL4}} set previous in my script, but i need to make a validation if the specific value exists in the page.

I tried the following code but seems the format is wrong

```
SET !VAR4 EVAL("var q = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\\'{{!COL4}}'\\/ig); if (!q) MacroError(\"ERROR - NO RECORD FOUND\"); else 'FOUND';")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the correct format, thanks anyway!

```
SET !VAR4 EVAL("var q = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match('{{!COL4}}'); if (!q) MacroError(\"ERROR - NO RECORD FOUND IN FIND\"); else ('{{!COL4}}');")
```